# do-while loop to count digits in an inputted number. trouble shooting code

Tags: java, do-while, counting, digits

I can't seem to figure this out. It always displays that the number has 4 digits. I capped the input limit at 4 digits, as I'm sure you can see.

I have tried changing the modulus operators and other basic solutions.

//March 28th 2019
   /*Write a Java program using a do while loop that takes a positive or negative integer input from the user and reports how many digits that number contains.
 * The loop should quit when the user enters 0. Hint: Use % to access each digit and / to reduce the number, so you can count all the digits.
*/

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Do_While_Swigart
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    int number = 0;
    int var = 0;
    int var2, var3,var4,var5,var6 = 0;
    int count = 0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Hello! Please input a positive or negative whole number. Ex: 450");

    number = scan.nextInt();



    do 
    {
      var = number % 10;

      count = (var/var);

      var2 = number % 100;

      count += (var2/var2);

      var3 = number %100;

      count += (var3/var3);

      var4 = number%1000;

      count += (var4/var4);

      var5 = number%10000;


    } while ( var5 == 0);

    System.out.println("Your number has "+count+" digits.");
  }

}
```

Comment: it would probably be easiest to do  (number+"").length

Comment: Attach a debugger and step through the code. Pay close attention to what var, var2, var3 and var4 get assigned - as well as what (var/var) evaluates (hint x/x=1 when x != 0)

Comment: Alternatively, the math-y way to do length of a number in digits is `1 + floor(log(n))` where `log` is in the same base as the number. If `n` can be negative go just add `1 + floor(log(abs(n)))`

Comment: Your approach can't work. Take an input of 1000 for example. 1000%10 = 0. Oh oh. divide by 0 error.

Comment: /10 removes a digit

Comment: @KevinO that won't work: not only because the number may be negative, if it is positive you got an infinite loop `number /= number` result in `1` which is `> 0` (have not tested, but pretty sure)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger, I'll grant you the negative number; and I made a typo in that it should be `while (number > 0) { ++count; number /= 10; }`; typing while multi-tasking. The essential example for positive numbers is here: https://ideone.com/3iivzs

Comment: ahh, and not too hard to make it work with negative numbers.... but I'll leave that for OP to figure out

Comment: @SwiggitySwoogity Can you please accept the answer if it answers your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code will solve your problem. Moreover, there is no need to use the % operator as there is no need to extract each digit. All you just need to count the number of digits and by using / operator you can iterate your loop and when the number has been reduced to zero the loop will exit.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NumberLength{



    public static void main(String ar[]){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Hello! Please input a positive or negative whole number. Ex: 450");

    int number = scan.nextInt();
    int countDig  = calNumOfDigit(number);
    System.out.println(countDig);
    }

    public static int calNumOfDigit(int n){
                int count = 0;
        int num = Math.abs(n);
        do{
            count++;
            num = num/10;

        }while(num>0);

        return count;
    }
}
```

Explanation with an example:-

Suppose the input number is: 450
count: 1
num: 450/10 = 45

count: 2
num: 45/10 = 4

count: 3
num: 4/10 = 0

while condition is num > 0 . So now the loop will exit.

Hope this helps you !!!

Answer (score 0):

This code takes into account all requirements of the problem. Strange as it may be.

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n=-420; // input 
        int digits=0;

        do {
            if (n != 0) // quit if input should be 0
                digits++;
        } while ((n%Math.pow(10,digits)) != n); // a=b%c --> if c > b then a = b 

        System.out.println(n + " has " + digits + " digits");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As jonathan said it's better to use something like:

Integer.toString(number).length();

but if you really need to do it with do while loop this could work for you:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Hello! Please input a positive or negative whole number. Ex: 450");

    int number = scan.nextInt();

    do {
        int digitos = (int) (Math.log10(number) + 1);

        number = number / 10;

        System.out.println("Your number has " + digitos + " digits.");

    } while (number < 0);
```

Comment: Now you print a different number of digits multiple times because your print is in the loop.

Comment: will work a **bit** weird for negative numbers (@John3136 the loop will only loop if the number is `-10` or less)